# PHP APC DLL Built with VC8

Tags: php, dll, apc, vc8

I am looking for a copy php_apc.dll that was built with VC8. I found one built with VC9, but my PHP distro I got with the ZendServer CE says it needs to be built with VC8.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

This is the [base](http://pecl.php.net/package/apc) , [built](https://ma.ttias.be/how-to-compile-and-install-php-extensions-from-source/) it. I can't assist more, lack of information given.

This is so old, a note for future visitor that this is related to PHP 5 where PHP 7 and 8 already released.